# A lot of json files import to mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I have over a million of .json files. Every file contains just one data.

I don't want to merge all json files because it is difficult and exhausting for my server

I tried to import one by one, it worked but i tried to import to directory, it couldn't worked.

I used this code:

> mongoimport --db DBName --collection CollName --type json --file C:\Users\admin\Desktop\1428714829\ --jsonArray

How can i import all files?

Answer (score 0):

The mongoimport utility imports data exported using mongoexport - it is not a generic tool to import arbitrary JSON documents.

You will need to write your own script which reads the JSON files and inserts the content into Mongo.